# How to solve the issue of fread txt with EOF?

Tags: r, import, data.table

I am trying to read the climate station info from ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/ghcn/daily/ghcnd-stations.txt.
However, since the first row is not fully populated (last two cols are missing) and the 5th column contains spaces, I am unable to complete reading with:

```
fread('ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/ghcn/daily/ghcnd-stations.txt',sep=)
```

It returns error message:

```
 Expected sep (' ') but new line, EOF (or other non printing character) ends 
 field 5 when detecting types from point 0: AGE00135039  35.7297    0.6500   
 50.0    ORAN-HOPITAL MILITAIRE
```

How to apply fread correctly on reading this txt file? Thank you!

Comment: Ok, if I'm reading this correctly, fixed-width format of this sort is on the todo list: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1345

Comment: You can try reading it into one column only and then break it down into all 8 or so variables, but it is going to be a bit painful

Comment: Thank you @Frank, that helps and I will take a look.

Comment: Thank you @ira. Just thought there was a simpler way to force R fread the txt into 8 columns. However, the spaces is indeed an issue too. Maybe fixed-width format suggested by Frank is a potential solution.

Comment: @penelope I think there are actually 8 columns. There are US state abbreviations lower down the table.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @ira. I didn't even noticed that yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just try the `read.fwf` function from the utils package? Column widths are given in the readme.txt file (see section IV).

```
IV. FORMAT OF "ghcnd-stations.txt"

------------------------------
Variable   Columns   Type
------------------------------
ID            1-11   Character
LATITUDE     13-20   Real
LONGITUDE    22-30   Real
ELEVATION    32-37   Real
STATE        39-40   Character
NAME         42-71   Character
GSN FLAG     73-75   Character
HCN/CRN FLAG 77-79   Character
WMO ID       81-85   Character
------------------------------
```

However, the following attempt returns an error:

```
data <- read.fwf("ghcnd-stations.txt", widths = c(11,9,10,7,3,31,4,4,6))
Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
  line 25383 did not have 7 elements
```

Inspection of line 25,383 reveals the cause of the error.

```
> x <- readLines("ghcnd-stations.txt", 25383)
> tail(x, 1)
[1] "CA002100627  60.8167 -137.7333  846.0 YT HAINES APPS #4                              "
```

So, circumvent this by including the `comment.char` argument, changing the value from the default (#) to something else, probably just the null.

```
data <- read.fwf("ghcnd-stations.txt", widths = c(11,9,10,7,3,31,4,4,6), comment.char="")
```

It only takes about 20 seconds. No real need for `fread`.

Comment: really thank you for the suggestion. I asked this question when I started using fread function and thought there might be a way to solve the issue I met. Thanks for the suggestion of using read.fwf which I didn't use before. I will try!